# User activation mail preview, wrong activation link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I was adding account activation following the tutorial on railstutorial.org.
Account activation by visiting the generated link works if I copy the link from the console, where the mail is shown in the server logs. However, the mail preview you can find under http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation contains another, false link. The name in the greeting matches, therefore only the token is wrong. Please find some relevant code below:

test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview 
# Preview this email at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation
  def account_activation
    user = User.last
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user)
  end
```

the mail html.erb:

```
<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>
<p>Welcome. Click below to activate account </p> 
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

in the User model:

```
attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
      before_save   :downcase_email
      before_create :create_activation_digest
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  private
    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
```

and the controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
             @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Do you have any idea why in the mail preview a token different from the one in the serverlogs gets generated?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could possibly be confusing you. The first is that the names matching on both email templates could be just due to the fact that you stored the exact same names for two different users. The second reason is that every time you visit http://.../account_activation, a new activation_token is generated for the **first** user in the development database.

Per the instructions  on the tutorial:

> Note that Listing 10.16 also assigns a value to user.activation_token,
>   which is necessary because the account activation templates in Listing
>   10.12 and Listing 10.13 need an account activation token.

found at https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-account_activation_preview